# Creating a UIButton in a subclass of UIButton

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, subclass

I am trying to create a UIButton in a class that is a subclass of UIButton. The reason for this is that it would be easier for my app to do this. I am wondering if it is possible. I am able to create the button, but the action is not working. My selector exists, but is not getting called.

```html
        UIButton *button2 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, kThumbSide - 350, kThumbSide, 16)];
        [button2 setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button2 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [data objectForKey:@"username"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button2 sizeToFit];
        button2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        button2.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
        button2.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15];
        [button2 addTarget:delegate action:@selector(showUserViews) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self addSubview:button2];
```

Comment: Show the code of class which inherits UIButton.

Comment: This is the method that I use. -(id)initWithIndex:(int)i andData:(NSDictionary*)data { . The class has some other things like a label, but it mostly uses an AFNetworkingOperation to do some stuff with a UIImage.

Comment: If you implemented above code in UIButton subclass then it would not be work, because you adding button inside another button as per my understanding... would you please describe more regarding above issue?

Comment: @Amol yeah, that is what I am trying to do. Seems like it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you are creating an **Object** of **UIButton** class not any **Class** clear???
and your target method are getting wrong **Delegate**.
try it

```
[button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(showUserViews) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

replace **delegate** with **self** for getting `showUserViews` method in same class

Comment: That doesn't work either. Forgot to mention I had already tried that. And what I meant was that my UIButton OBJECT is in a class that is a SUBCLASS of UIButton also. I know it sounds weird, but its true, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't see any UIButton subclass here, perhaps you've asked your question wrong.

> Any way you should do this:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad]
    UIButton *b = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:YOUR_DESIRED_FRAME];
    [b setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]]
    [b addTarget:self action:@selector(bPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]
}

 - (void)bPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"b button pressed")
 }
```

Comment: I am saying that the method is in a class that is a subclass of UIButton. Like so: http://gyazo.com/b7ea9b3f323f9113256a0b5b97822b72 I did that to create a custom button for the class, but now want to create another button inside of it.